# Some French accented characters are encoded as utf-8 but still not rendering properly

Tags: r, utf-8, stringr

Hi there: I'm importing a Stata file that has a lot of French accented characters. The on import, I set the Encoding to utf-8. However, some of the accented characters are not rendering properly. See a sample of rows from my data-set below.
How do I handle this?

```
test<-tibble::tribble(
  ~municipality,
  "Sainte-Anne-de-Beaupré",
  "Sainte-Anne-de-Beaupré",
  "Sainte-Anne-de-Beaupré",
  "BeauprÃ©",
  "BeauprÃ©",
  "BeauprÃ©",
  "BeauprÃ©",
  "BeauprÃ©",
  "BeauprÃ©"
)
Encoding(test$municipality)
Encoding(test$municipality)<-'utf-8'
test$municipality
```

Comment: It is possible that the original file was wrongly encoded (probably double encoded: encoded to UTF-8, read it as it was Latin1 and encoded again as UTF-8).

Comment: Yes, entirely possible. I did not create the original file. Is there a way I can get around that? Or might I have to do a find and replace in Excel and reimport?

Comment: Could you show the image of the texts (in the original file) that aren't rendered properly in R?

Comment: I would do so. If that was the case, you should just check for Â and Ã (as first character). There are also not many possible second characters.

Answer (score 0):

As Giacomo mentions this seems to be an example of files where part of it (as you show also correct encoded é's where UTF-8, read it as it was Latin1 and encoded again as UTF-8, this means your encoding is correct as Ã© itself are utf-8 characters as well and displayed as such. What you can do is fix such errors in the past.

Knowing how it happened means we know how to fix it!

So I wrote a function in the past (it supports some major screw ups of tripple wrong encodings) so we simulate how each character becomes after wrong encoding and then saved as utf8 again.

```
FixEncoding <- function() {
  # create the unicode ranges from https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html
  range <- c(sprintf("%x", seq(strtoi("0xa0"), strtoi("0xff"))))
  unicode <- vapply(range, FUN.VALUE = character(1), function(x) { parse(text = paste0("'\\u00", x, "'"))[[1]] })
  # add the ones that are missing (red ones in https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html)
  unicode <- c(c("\u0168", "\u0152", "\u017d", "\u0153", "\u017e", "\u0178", "\u2019", "\u20ac", "\u201a", "\u0192", "\u201e", "\u2026", "\u2020", "\u2021", "\u02c6", "\u2030", "\u0160", "\u2030"), unicode)
  once <- vapply(unicode, FUN.VALUE = character(1), function(x) { 
    Encoding(x) <- "Windows-1252"
    iconv(x, to = "UTF-8")
  })
  fix_once <- unicode
  names(fix_once) <- once
  twice <- vapply(once, FUN.VALUE = character(1), function(x) { 
    Encoding(x) <- "Windows-1252"
    iconv(x, to = "UTF-8")
  })
  fix_twice <- unicode
  names(fix_twice) <- twice
  triple <- vapply(twice, FUN.VALUE = character(1), function(x) { 
    Encoding(x) <- "Windows-1252"
    iconv(x, to = "UTF-8")
  })
  fix_triple <- unicode
  names(fix_triple) <- triple
  fixes <- c(fix_triple, fix_twice, fix_once)
  return(fixes)
}

fixes <- FixEncoding()
```

Lets run it on your data

```
v <- c("Sainte-Anne-de-Beaupré", "BeauprÃ©")
v
# [1] "Sainte-Anne-de-Beaupré" "BeauprÃ©"

stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(v, names(fixes), fixes, vectorize_all = F)
# [1] "Sainte-Anne-de-Beaupré" "Beaupré"
```

Another example:

```
str <- "\u006C\u00E9\u006C\u00E8\u006C\u00F6\u006C\u00E3"
str
# [1] "lélèlölã"

# how to corrupt it once
Encoding(str) <- "Windows-1252"
str <- iconv(str, to = "UTF-8")
str
# [1] "lÃ©lÃ¨lÃ¶lÃ£"

# add once, twice and tripple wrong encoded string to messy
messy <- c("lÃ©lÃ¨lÃ¶lÃ£", "lÃƒÂ©lÃƒÂ¨lÃƒÂ¶lÃƒÂ£", "lÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â©lÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¨lÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¶lÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â£")

# All three strings above would be fixed
stri_replace_all_fixed(messy, names(fixes), fixes, vectorize_all = F)
# [1] "lélèlölã" "lélèlölã" "lélèlölã"
```

Comment: I hope you didn't do that just for me! Plus, I'm working on a Mac Environment. Do I need to change this: ```Encoding(x) <- "Windows-1252"```

Comment: So this works on the example that Merijn provided, but it is still not working on my actual dataset. I may have to try to do a simple find and Replace, but I would really love to find an automated solution to this. Is there any way I can diagnose this further?

Comment: No I did not write this for answering this topic, I had to deal a while ago myself with csv files that were full of wrongly opened and back saved files with wrong encodings. You can try to figure out by trial and error what the "Windows-1252" would have been but you cannot see that anywhere as it had already been saved back to utf-8. Try Latin-1 for example or the most common encoding used where the files have been opened/saved. For Mac not sure how the encodings are named.

Comment: The principle remains the same though, if you know the encoding, you can simulate how the wrong ones would look like and then replace them back.

Comment: And if I don't know the encodings? I'm working on another stata file and it's the same problem and this is not doing the trick.